# Latex on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: latex, amazon-linux

I'm trying to get up and running with latex on Amazon Linux 2. I have done

```
sudo yum install texlive-pdftex
```

When I run `pdftex` I get:

```
fmtutil: config file `fmtutil.cnf' not found.
I can't find the format file `pdftex.fmt'!
```

I try running `fmtutil-sys --all` and I get

```
/usr/bin/fmtutil: line 395: /usr/share/texlive/texmf/texconfig/tcfmgr: No such file or directory
fmtutil: config file `fmtutil.cnf' not found.
```

Is anyone running pdftex on Amazon Linux 2? Any idea what my problem is?